# Visual Studio 2010 generated executable size larger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, size, executable

I've got an C++ application originally written with Visual Studio 6.0

The application is standard and raw Win32 API, no MFC(*Edit 2), no .NET, statically linked, multi-threaded executable.

I have migrated through all versions of Visual Studio up to 2010 (today) and never had any problems until now:

**It compiles and runs perfectly with VS2010 BUT the generated executable size is four (4) times larger!**

I've tried all the options I know (optimizations, **remove debug info**, etc..) with no results. Granted, I am new to VS2010, but not to Visual Studio.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Again: I am NOT using any frameworks, it is a raw, statically linked, Win32 application, no DLLs, no ODBC, no network, no .NET

Hoping to see my executables small once again, I thank you for any input.

- Edit 1: 
  Original Size=626KB  (VS6.0, VS2008)
  Bloated size=2.013KB (VS2010)
- Edit 2:
  After some research and dumps, I discovered a hidden reference to MFC.
  Originally I said it did NOT use MFC, but it does.

Comment: It's probably either the statically linked or maybe a linker setting changed in VS2010 to generate larger sections by default for better caching or something. What order of magnitude are we talking about here - 4K to 16K? 64K to 256K? 1MB to 4MB?

Comment: What does 4-times larger mean? Megabyte? Five megabytes?

Comment: I've edited the question to include sample sizes, this happens to all my applications.

Comment: I have no degree in mathematics but from 626kb to 2013kb is in my calculator 3 times larger....your are still on 32bits?

Comment: Is is exactly 3.21, but it varies, on some projects the difference is larger, in some less. No, I am developing on a 64bit machine with Win7, but the generated executable MUST be 32bit (It is a project requirement)

Comment: I think some references might have been added by Visual Studio when the solution was converted. Here's why I think so: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/469785/mfc-of-vs2010-generate-a-very-large-exe-file http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vcmfcatl/thread/fcf7fa2c-5263-4bfe-a352-a75485ac6cd2

Comment: What does dumpbin tell you about the various dependents and segment sizes?

Comment: I originally said it did not use MFC, it does. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increase in size may be caused by changes to the MFC. [Here](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/statically-linked-release-mfc-exe-size-in-visual-c-2010-vs-2008/) is an explanation, and [here](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/how-to-make-small-statically-linked-mfc-exes-in-visual-c-2010/) is a workaround by the same author that brings the executable's size back down into regions where it was with 2008. The workaround involves editing copies of MFC source files, though, a process not everybody may be happy with, and which needs to be repeated after every update, e.g. after installing a Visual Studio service pack.

Update:

It looks like the OP does not use MFC, so these might be two different issues. I have experienced the size increase myself but unfortunately cannot say whether caused by MFC or not since my project statically links to the MFC.

Comment: That's very neat, though I can't see why you'd want to statically link rather than dynamically link anyway though now MFC lives in WinSxS. The OP says he isn't using MFC, though.

Comment: You want to link statically when you write command-line tools which you want to distribute as EXEs without installer and MFC runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using static linking, I suggest using the linker switches if you are compiling at the command line using the syntax:

cl /Ox [your C++ source file(s)] [libraries required if any] [resource files required if any] /link /FILEALIGN:512 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /INCREMENTAL:NO

If you are building within the Visual Studio IDE, you check the linker settings by selecting the project properties from the menu. In the configuration, select the Release and then click the linker settings found on the left pane, this will show you a list of configurations corresponding to the linker settings currently set by default.

In the Command Line under the linker, specify the option /FILEALIGN:512 in the Additional options entry then click the Apply button. In the General option under the linker, disable the incremental linking by selecting No(/INCREMENTAL:NO ). In the debugging option of the linker, select No for Generate Debug Info. For the linker optimization, you select the Eliminate Unreferenced Data(/OPT:REF) in the References and Remove Redundant COMDATs(/OPT:ICF) in the Enable COMDAT folding.

For the compiler optimization, make sure the Release configuration is selected, click the C/C++ tree view on the left pane and under that, click the Optimization, Select Full Optimization(/Ox). In the General setting under C/C++, Select Disabled for the Debug Information Format.

Don't forget to click the Apply button for every changes you make.

I hope everything I've mentioned here would be helpful to you and all of these applies to Visual C++ 2005 and 2008 but hopefully, it would also apply to Visual C++ 2010, if not, kindly check the documentation included with your Visual C++ 2010 installation.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you've left the default platform target at "Any CPU"?  If so, change it to x86 for 32-bit only code.  I'm guessing that will make up most of the difference.  The remainder is likely in changes in compiler optimizations (more aggressive loop unrolling and whatnot where size has been traded for speed since RAM is cheap).  I believe all the granular optimizations are still available from the command line, but many have been obscured in the UI options panels.

Comment: This setting applies to .NET projects, not the case of the questionned problem (native compile)

Comment: no, I've tried that also. The problem is 90% surely what I commented above: While migrating the proyect, MFC got its way back in, but right now I don't have time to check where exactly that is. As soon as I get some free time I'll check and post the final conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

See [Are there any tools for tracking down bloat in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141555/are-there-any-tools-for-tracking-down-bloat-in-c/3141613#3141613) - some techniques how to analyze what contributes to the executable size are described there. Once you perform analysis on both VC 6 and VS 2010 output, hopefully you will find something useful.

There is one particular gotcha which has hit me when porting from VC 6 to some Visual Studio edition: meaning of some optimization options has changed and the values I was using in the VC 6 project were no longer supported, and as a result the exe produced by VS was not optimized at all, causing both executable bloat and slow performance. Check your optimization settings in Properties/C/C++/Optimization and make sure optimization is on /Ox, /O2 or /O1.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in VS2010 Microsoft added functionality allowing HTML components in a dialog windows so a bunch of stuff is pulled in and linked in even if you aren't using it and the optimizations and options and removing unreferenced code do not help.  There is not a "good" way of removing the code, but there are some hacked up ways.  We compile our size-critical stuff on VS2008 still because of this.  Side note, our non-GUI code actually compiles smaller for what that's worth.  Hoping MS comes up with an option for this in a fix/patch so I can do everything on VS2010 but I'm not holding my breath...