# Tools for tracking down code bloat with GCC/CLANG

Tags: c++, templates, profiling

(I am looking for something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3141555/84349) but with a GCC/Linux focus).

I have a lot of template-heavy (as in "template-only") code that makes use of a lot of metaprogramming and special case optimizations.
The resulting binaries are very large and compile times are high.

Now I would like to check which function templates generate the most inline assembly code.
How can I do this?

Some context:

- We have a C++ template library with heavy algorithmic components.
  The original author focused on runtime speed instead and did not think about compile time speed so much.
- I would like to improve the compile time speed but keep the runtime speed constant, thus putting some decisions to runtime instead of compile time.
- The first step in this is IMO is to see which function templates are heaviest in terms of instantiation copies.
- A next step would be to combine this information with how heavily they are used in in a profiler and only keep the many special cases with compile-time choice for the hot inner loops.

Is this the right way to go? Any pro tips?

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer.

First solve the run-time issue by [*this method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

That will probably take several iterations, and it won't be easy.

Then learn to read the .map file.
You'll see in there which classes are taking big fractions of the size.
Take them out by trial-and-error, until you get down to what you actually need.